# What would cause a click operation to timeout after 60 seconds?

Tags: c#, selenium, webdriver

What would cause a click operation to timeout after 60 seconds? I get an exception thrown, even though the element is clearly displayed in the page and is clickable (I have a `ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable` check before the click). `OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException : The HTTP request to the remote WebDriver server for URL http://grid:4444/wd/hub/session/9e9693f0-0288-47a1-97f9-8f61c300bc41/element/29/click timed out after 60 seconds. ----> System.Net.WebException : The operation has timed out`

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(this.driverController.driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30.00));
IWebElement clickThis;
wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.Id("elementId")));
clickThis = this.driverController.driver.FindElement(By.Id("elementId"));
clickThis.Click();
```

The exception occurs at `clickThis.Click()`

Thanks,

Comment: Hey Matt, can you show us some markup?

Comment: @Matt if you provide the HTML of the page you are testing we could provide further advice on your problem..

Comment: Provide further info on your problem if it persists, or mark the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your exception indicates that it is the selenium grid hub that causes the timeout. The hub itself has a timeout, which works as described in the selenium documentation and below:

> -timeout 30 (300 is default) The timeout in seconds before the hub automatically releases a node that hasn't received any requests for
>   more than the specified number of seconds. After this time, the node
>   will be released for another test in the queue. This helps to clear
>   client crashes without manual intervention. To remove the timeout
>   completely, specify -timeout 0 and the hub will never release the
>   node.

If the issue would have been related to finding the element you wish to interact with, you should have receive a NoSuchElementException or similiar.